# how to get remote mysql database dump to my local machine?

Tags: mysql

I have remote server credentials and mysql root password. When I access remote machine and trying to take dump  it throws "'Got error 28 from storage engine' when trying to dump tablespaces". So I plan to take the dump from my local machine. So,how can I take the database dump. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error 28 means you don't have enough disk space

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/mysql-error-28-and-solution/

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen that error so got curious and googled it.

http://drupal.org/node/44160 seems to suggest you are out of space on your HD.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue right after filling /tmp to 100% doing a temp backup.